# Creating custom view

Tags: android

I want to create a custom view `TestView` class for which I can create object via `new TestView()`.
A new view class however needs a AttributeSet object. From where do I get that AttributeSet and what does it have to include?

Answer (score 10):

It's not mandatory, and most times you don't even have to worry about it as long as you provide constructors from `View` that pass them along to `super()`.

```
public CustomView(Context context)  // No Attributes in this one.
{
  super(context);
  // Your code here
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
  super(context, attrs);
  // Your code here
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int default_style)
{
  super(context, attrs, default_style);
  // Your code here
}
```

`View` takes care of doing the heavy lifting for dealing with all of the `android:*` attributes that you'd usually pass in when adding the view to a layout.  Your constructors could make use of those attributes or your own if you've defined them:

```
<com.blrfl.CustomView
 android:id="@+id/customid"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 blrfl:foo="bar"
 blrfl:quux="bletch"
/>
```

Comment: I spent many hours trying to generate an attrs set on the fly, i found it near on impossible to find any documentation or examples on how to do this. A good question might be how to set the foo and quux properties when not using attrs, and using new CustomView().

Comment: CustomView(String foo, String bletch) perhaps.

Comment: Ask it and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Questioned asked here, let me know if its an appropriate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495511/android-how-to-pass-custom-component-parameters-in-java-and-xml

Answer (score 0):

Either of 3 constructor provided by view class can be implemented.. so providing constructor with attributeset is not mandatory.